# How can I find the number of orders for every distinct customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id     INT     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    address     VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    city        VARCHAR(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
    state       VARCHAR(2)  DEFAULT NULL,
    zip_code    VARCHAR(5)  DEFAULT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id        INT     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id         INT     NOT NULL,
    order_placed_date   DATE    NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
);
```

It's the end of 2018, and the owner of the factory wants to write an SQL query that finds the COUNT of orders placed in 2018 by customer e-mail address. She wants to ORDER the results by the COUNT of orders placed in 2018, descending, so that she can personally send thank-you e-mails to top customers by order volume.
I have to write a query that will help the owner to find the COUNT of all orders placed in 2018, by customer e-mail address, sorted descending

I made an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT email FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id;
```

but I have to count the orders for every distinct customer, So I will have another column total_orders for the year 2018.

How can I make the WHERE clause for the year? I have the placed_order_date in date format.
How can I count the number of orders for every customer_id?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select customers.email, count(*)
from orders
inner join customers using (customer_id)
where orders.placed_order_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
group by customers.email
```

You would likely want an index on orders.placed_order_date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query

```
SELECT customers.email, count(order_id) as totalCount FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id where year(order_placed_date)=2018 group by customers.email order by totalCount  desc
```